# apply: private method open called for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

- Rails version:4.2
- Ruby version:2.2

  Line = rails new appcomposer -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
- the code displays the following error

/home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:226:in `apply': private method` open' called for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: What line does raise this error?

Comment: Do you really need old Ruby / Rails for new project?

Comment: I hit enter before revising the question, forgive me !

Comment: yes i am using a tool called rails composer

Comment: *What line does raise this error?* Is it full log?

Comment: the line that generates the error is this = rails new (name of project) -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error by uninstalling the latest versions of "thor" and using only the version.

```
gem uninstall thor --version (version)
```